# How to prevent accidental publish Python pacakge using setup.py

Tags: python

Is there a way to prevent accidental publication of private package such as `"private": true` in NPM?

Comment: What do you want to do?  Your python package won't upload unless you upload it.

Comment: I want to prevent accidental publication. I'm afraid to run `python setup.py register` by my mistake.

Comment: I do not agree with the close votes: though it can be considered as a stupid question (no offense), it's still a good, precise and on topic question for stack overflow which can accept an answer…

Comment: It's not a stupid question. I found the following answer, although I do wish this would be programmed into the setup function. http://www.tomaz.me/2013/09/03/prevent-accidental-publishing-of-a-private-python-package.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

well, there's no such thing as a `private` option. You should just avoid doing `python setup.py register` by mistake. Aren't you afraid of doing `rm -rf /` by mistake? or `rm /boot/linux*`? ;-)

In case you do run `python setup.py register` by mistake, you can always log on pypi and delete manually your package from the index.

Answer (score 4):

You can add something like this to the top of your setup.py script:

```
import sys

for arg in sys.argv:
    if arg in ('upload', 'register', 'testarg'):
        print('This setup is not designed to be uploaded or registered.')
        sys.exit(-1)
```

You can test it works safely by doing:

```
python setup.py testarg
```

This should display a message and immediately exit.

Comment: This works and is along the lines of https://www.tomaz.me/2013/09/03/prevent-accidental-publishing-of-a-private-python-package.html